# Unable to write file with Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Trying to write a simple log file with Electron, works fine while developing but fails once the app is packaged

```
logFilePath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), 'output/' + moment().format('YYYYMMDD') + '.log'),
logger = fs.createWriteStream(logFilePath, {flags: 'a+'});
```

and the package.json part for unpacking files looks like this

```
    "asarUnpack": [
        "./output/*"
    ],
```

error message is ENOENT: no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a comma at the end of the first line?

Running your code without the  comma and declaring the variables:

```
let logFilePath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), 'output/' + moment().format('YYYYMMDD') + '.log')
console.log('logFilePath', logFilePath);

let logger = fs.createWriteStream(logFilePath, {flags: 'a+'});
console.log('logger', logger);
```

---

```
logFilePath /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/file-launcher/output/20210318.log

logger WriteStream {
  _writableState: WritableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    finalCalled: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    destroyed: false,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: true,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    afterWriteTickInfo: null,
    bufferedRequest: null,
    lastBufferedRequest: null,
    pendingcb: 0,
    prefinished: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: false,
    autoDestroy: false,
    bufferedRequestCount: 0,
    corkedRequestsFree: {
      next: null,
      entry: null,
      finish: [Function: bound onCorkedFinish]
    }
  },
  writable: true,
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  path: '/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/file-launcher/output/20210318.log',
  fd: null,
  flags: 'a+',
  mode: 438,
  start: undefined,
  autoClose: true,
  pos: undefined,
  bytesWritten: 0,
  closed: false
}
```